# jQuery Easy UI Portal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to test the [Portal](http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/portal.php) extension from the [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/) framework but for some reason I keep getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'portal'`. Does anybody have an idea why is this happening? Am I missing a resource in the fiddle or something?

Here's the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rW24a/1/

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the extension AFTER importing jQuery itself?

Comment: Please view the link to the fiddle

Comment: I think what Robin wants to know is: did you add the import tags? e.g. 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.portal.js"></script>

Comment: These are all resources that have been added to the fiddle

Comment: For whatever reason jsFiddle is not loading the portal.js file. Add it manually and it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/rW24a/2/

Comment: @SalvadorDali No, they are all listed in the managed resources tab. The portal js file is not loading regardless.

Comment: when run fiddle, the portal script does not show up in network resources. Domain may not allow hot linking to the script